# iframe content overlapping the iframe’s boundaries

Tags: html, css, object, iframe, embed

I have a `header` with a specific height. Inside it, I want to place/load an external html file containing a drop-down menu.

```
<head>
    <style>
        header {
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <iframe src="dropDownMenu.html"></iframe>
    </header>
    <main>[...]</main>
    <footer>[...]</footer>
</body>
```

The problem is that the dropped-down items don’t go over the `iframe` itself nor the header (definitely because of the specific height in the `header` and the `iframe` boundary itself).

I have tried with big numbers in the `z-index` for both the iframe and the external menu file itself with no result. I also have tried with `embed` and `object` as well.

It is posible for an iframe content to overlap the iframe’s boundaries. And if so, can it be done using only HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you used CSS Position before you use the z-index. Because if not, then is not really working since it required the CSS Position.

For more info about the CSS Position, you can check this link.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: How exactly should I use `position` for this?

Comment: For example.

iframe {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}